# Clojure RegEx: How to embed comments inside regular expression?

Tags: regex, clojure

I'm looking for a way to embed comments into regular expressions in Clojure explaining what this or that piece of code does. I couldn't find 
such feature in the docs.

Having the following regex in Clojure:

```clj
 #"\$[A-Z]+|\((?:(?:\$[A-Z]+|[\w\'\-\_]+)(?:\|(?:\$[A-Z]+|[\w\'\-\_]+))*)\)"
```

How do I add comments in the regular expression? In Perl I would stick with using a trailing `/x` modifier like:

```perl
$_ =~ m/ abc    # some comment explaining what abc is about
         /x;
```

This makes it easy to deal with it some days later.

How do I go about doing it in Clojure?

Comment: Maybe `#"(?x)\$[A-Z]+|\((?:(?:\$[A-Z]+|[\w'-]+)(?:\|(?:\$[A-Z]+|[\w'-]+))*)\)"`?

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew, this looks promising!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the embedded flag option (or [inline modifier](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers)) `(?x)`:

```
(str #"(?x)                          # Turn on COMMENTS mode
       \$[A-Z]+|                     # $ and 1+ ASCII letters or
       \(                            # ( char
          (?:                        # Start of a non-capturing group:
           (?:\$[A-Z]+|[\w'-]+)      # $ and 1+ ASCII letters or 1+ word, ' or - chars
           (?:                       # Start of a non-capturing group:
             \|(?:\$[A-Z]+|[\w'-]+)  # |, $ and 1+ ASCII letters or 1+ word, ' or - chars
          )*                         # End of the inner non-capturing group, repeat 0 or more times
         )                           # End of the outer non-capturing group
       \)                            # ) char
       "
)
```

**NOTE**:

- Since the regex engine used is that of Java, all literal regular spaces,   must be escaped even inside character classes.
- To use a literal `#` in the pattern, escape it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd split it into multiple strings and then concatenate them; something like:

```
(def a "aaa")
(def b "bbb")
(def c "ccc")
(def my-regex (re-pattern (str a b c)))
```